# How to derive that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-a)!} = {1\over{(-a)}!}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

According to Wolfram alpha:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-a)!} = {1\over{(-a)}!}$$

Is this correct? How can we arrive at this equality? I would think that this limit diverges since
$ \frac{n!}{(n-a)!} = n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-a+1) $ which should diverge as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: What's the definition of $b!$ where $b<0$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson $z!$ is defined for complex numbers via the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: @xojfqa What exactly did you type in Wolfram Alpha? I didn't get that result.

Comment: @jjagmath: It's still not defined for negative integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you got that answer, but Wolfram Alpha does not say that. It says

$$\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{n!}{(n-a)!} = \frac{1}{(-a)!}.$$

Rather, we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{(n-a)!} = \infty$$

if $a$ is positive, and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{(n-a)!} = 0$$

if $a$ is negative.

If $a=0$ then the limit is $1$.